# Best choice for database for sorted inserts

Tags: mysql, database, sorting, redis, nosql

I need a database that can perform sorted inserts extremely fast.

The amount of data stored at a time will be very less. I want inserts and deletes at a very high rate and the only query i have to perform on my data is sort. But i want an O(1) for my query. Is there any such NoSQL database that can sort the data during insert itself?

Comment: You can use an embedded btree database. They sort during insert. Then you can use a cursor to retrieve the sorted items. Moving the cursor is usually O(1). Using point lookups is O(logn), but still very fast. You can try leveldb, berkeleydb or hamsterdb which I always recommend and which works the way I just described (disclaimer: I wrote it ;) )

Answer (score 2):

Redis has support for sorted sets (see http://redis.io/topics/data-types). Using this solution you will have following time complexities for operations:

- ZADD (equivalent of insert) - O(log(N)) for each item added, where N is the number of elements in the sorted set
- ZREM (eqiuvalent of delete) -  O(M*log(N)) with N being the number of elements in the sorted set and M the number of elements to be removed
- ZSCAN (equivalent of select) - O(1) for every call. O(N) for a complete iteration, including enough command calls for the cursor to return back to 0. N is the number of elements inside the collection.